# are duplicate (identical) figure captions allowed?

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm hacking through a DOORS DXL script provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266029/doors-dxl-export-to-pdf-or-print-with-a-given-template/13289643#13289643) (stackoverflow), and am running into difficulty getting all the images contained in the DOORS module to show up in the correct location in the output document. Most of the images get thrown into the end of the output PDF.
The current DXL script I've set up passes the text in each image attribute, which is DOORS' default `<picture>` text, as the caption.  I know I need to fix other stuff in the script, but to save me some time, can you tell me whether the indexing done by `xelatex` or `lualatex` can handle multiple instances of this identical `caption` and `label` in the following snippet cause a problem?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PF_FE_DGD_551.png}
\label{fig:<Picture>}
\caption{<Picture>}
\end{figure}
```

(The actual `png` name is different every time, and the images do show up in the document; just not in the right place)

Comment: the caption text can be anything, by using `[h]` you are specifying that the figure is hardly allowed in any place (normally it generates a warning) but you do not allow it at the top or bottom of a text page or on a page that only has figures, as you have excluded `t`, `b` and `p`, that makes it _very_ hard for latex to put the figure anywhere sensible. duplicate labels will generate an error, also `\label` has to be after `\caption` to do anything useful.

Comment: I am one of the people who maintains that code. If I were you, I'd believe me not some tutorial you found somewhere on the internet.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   Apologies for not recognizing your name.  I'll pull the official manual off the source site.